What other crewed spacecraft returned uncrewed before Starliner Boe-CFT?
Tonight's (September 6, 2024) return of Starliner (Boe-CFT or Boeing Crew Flight Test) from the ISS was made without the crew that launched with it (Suny Williams, Butch Wilmore). What other spacecraft that launched with a crew returned without one?

In general soviet space program focused on unsupervised flights - so any crew member going this or other way was basically a ballast

There was at least one that went up with a crew and returned without a live crew, depending on how you define ‘crew’ and ‘returned’.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany - thats a bit grim.. then yes, many more to add.. :/

Twice, iirc:
One is Soyuz MS-22 in 2023:

Damaged Russian Soyuz capsule lands back on Earth from space station
March 28 (Reuters) - A damaged Russian Soyuz MS-22 capsule landed back on Earth on Tuesday, three months after coolant began leaking from the craft while it was docked at the International Space Station (ISS).
The module completed the almost two-hour return from the ISS without a crew, landing in the Kazakh steppe on Tuesday afternoon, a few hundred kilometres from the Baikonur cosmodrome, home to Russia's space launches.
The landing was broadcast online by the Russian space agency Roscosmos. A significant coolant leak was discovered in the capsule last December - caused by a 0.8-millimetre hole in its outer skin.
A tiny meteorite is likely to have pierced the structure while it was docked, experts say. Images captured from the exterior of the ISS showed coolant fluid spewing into space, while Roscosmos said temperatures at one point rose to 30 Celsius (86 Fahrenheit) inside the capsule.
https://www.reuters.com/lifestyle/science/damaged-russian-soyuz-capsule-lands-back-earth-2023-03-28/

and Soyuz 32, 1979:
(Soyuz 32 had already docked successfully with Salyut 6 space station, but when Soyuz 33, with an identical engine, launched, problems occured, with it felt that 32 was not safe to return crewed. Subsequently, 34, with a different engine, was launched to return the crew.)

Soyuz 33 was launched 10 April with the fourth international crew in the Soviet Intercosmos program. But, as the craft approached to 1,000 metres, the engine failed and shut down after three seconds of a planned six-second burn. Rukavishnikov had to hold the instrument panel as the craft violently shook. A second firing attempt was made, but the engine shut down again, and Ryumin, observing from the station, reported an abnormal lateral glow from behind the Soyuz during the burn. Mission control accordingly aborted the mission and told the crew to prepare to return to Earth. It was the first in-orbit failure of the Soyuz propulsion system.
(Soyuz 32) with a now-questionable engine (it had the same type as Soyuz 33) ..(crew return).. was not considered the best option.
Soyuz 32 was loaded with 130 kg of replaced instruments, processed materials, exposed film and other items with a total weight equal to that of the two cosmonauts. On 13 June, it undocked and returned to Earth uncrewed 295 km northwest of Dzhezkazgan.
Soyuz 34, launched uncrewed on 6 June, docked at the just-vacated aft port of the space station on 9 June. The Soyuz had a new engine system, and its successful test flight gave the Salyut 6 crew a reliable return vehicle.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_32


I guess that leads to another question: Is Soyuz 34 the only spacecraft that launched uncrewed and returned with a crew? Should I post that as its own question?

You could! But in addition to 34 you can include MS-23 that was sent up to replace holed MS-22..!
